# Passing Parameter to Progress via Open Query from SQL Server - error Invalid date string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, openquery, progress-db

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and am using an OpenQuery to retrieve data from a Progress Database.

This is my query:

```
    DECLARE @SOMONTH DATE;
    SELECT @SOMONTH = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE (),-1));

    SELECT t2.[Amount]
    FROM OPENQUERY(MyServer, 
            ' select top 50 
            t1."trn-val" as "Amount"
      from myTable t1
  WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= '''''' + @SOMONTH + ''''''

 ') AS t2


/*
  Previous attempts -
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= '''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@SOMONTH,103) + '''''' 
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= ' + '''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@SOMONTH,103) + '''''' + ' 
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= '''''' + @SOMONTH + ''''''
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= ' + '''''' + @SOMONTH + '''''' + ' 
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= ''DATE(@SOMONTH)''
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= TO_DATE(''@SOMONTH'')
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= TO_DATE(''@SOMONTH'',''DD/MM/YYYY'')
 WHERE t1."trn-dte" >= ''@SOMONTH''
 */
```

However, I keep receiving the error:

```
[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Invalid date string (7497).
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From what I see you are trying to convert the variable in your previous attempts, try to convert it before you use it in the query into varchar(50) for instance.
The error indicates that the date in the remote table is invalid and 7497 is the charindex where it can be found.

Don't take my comment for a correct though, I'm just trying to see what could be wrong, doesn't necessarily mean its correct.

Comment: You're using string concatenation to create a query, not passing parameters. This exposes you to SQL injection issues *and* convertion problems. Construct the query string *before* using it with OPENQUERY, so you have a chance to inspect it. Create the date literal *before* constructing the query, preferably in an unambiguous format like `YYYY-MM-DD` and append that to the query with proper quoting. Eg `declare @date nvarchar(10)=convert(nvarchar(10),@SOMONTH,23)` to get the date string, `set @query=@query + '''' + @date + ''''` to quote and append the string

Comment: `OP` is you - original poster. What you posted isn't what I wrote though - for starters, there are too many single quotes in there. Second, instead of using a string query with `OPENQUERY` you've put `OPENQUERY` itself inside the string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 2 mins, missed pasting something

Comment: Don't use `EXEC`. Don't put `OPENQUERY` inside the string. There was nothing wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000)

declare @SOMONTH date

set @SOMONTH = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE (),-1));

DECLARE @Date nvarchar(10)=convert(nvarchar(10),@SOMONTH,23)

SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT top 50 * FROM OPENQUERY([myserver], ''SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE "trn-dte" >= ''''' + @Date + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Comment: That's still wrong. Ther'es absolutely no reason to use `OPENQUERY` inside the string, no reason to use `EXEC`

Comment: Doubly wrong too - instead of returning the first 50 rows from the linked table, this will return *everything* and then discard everything except the first 50 locally. the `TOP 50` clause, or the `FETCH NEXT ..` clause should appear in the remote query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you post what you mean please?  I don't understand how it will work without the OPENQUERY.  I'm only using TOP 50 for testing purposes - this will be removed going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Progress Knowledge base [000034986](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-format-a-DATE-TIME-DATETIME-or-DATETIME-WITH-TIMEZONE-variable-for-use-in-a-SQL-92-query) illustrates how to format a date, this is the first hit if you google on:

```
site:progress.com sql92 date
```

Since I prefer ISO dates over any other guess the format date, this then becomes:

```
select top 50 t1."trn-val" as "Amount"
from myTable t1 
where t1."trn-dte" >= { d 'yyyy-mm-dd' }
```

I am not sure if your @sodate is already in this format or if you need an additional convert around your adddate:

```
select @SOMONTH = convert( varchar, dateadd( day, 1, eomonth( getdate(), -1 ) ), 23 );
```